# How to configure jersey to avoid com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer giving problems?

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, servlets

I have managed to narrow down why I can't compile my project. It's a maven project meant to be an api REST, done on eclipse and the idea is for it to run on tomcat v6.

I had this configuration on the pom.xml:

```
<!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
         <version>1.19</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
         <version>1.19</version>
     </dependency>
```

Which gives me the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet`

And when I've tried removing jersey-servlet, since I've seen people say that they create trouble and I only need jersey-server and so on, I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I've been messing arround with a lot of configuration, trying to follow different solutions, but I believe the problem lies here. Could anyone tell me how to properly configure this?

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.CC.enterprise.rest.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>CC-HelloWorld</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<distributionManagement>
    <!-- Will be used when it is NOT a snapshot version -->
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>RepositoryProxy</name>
        <url>edited</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Will be used when IT IS a snapshot version -->
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>RepositoryProxy</name>
        <url>edited</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.CC.enterprise.rest.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the [`jersey-server`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server) dependency. Use only the [`jersey-servlet`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet) dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

And ensure the [`com.sun.jersey`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey) dependencies are using the same version. At the time of writing, the most recent version is `1.19.1`.

If it's a new project, forget the old *Jersey 1.x* and go for *Jersey 2.x*.

Comment: If I do that I get: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer . There are no more com.sun.jersey dependencies other than jersey-json if I remove that one. It's not new, it's based on another previous one that works with this configuration so the idea was to not spend too much time on this stuff. Ha!

Comment: @monkeyintern The `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` class in included in the `jersey-servlet` dependency. You should not have that error.

Comment: I don't know what else to do or where else to look. Run as: server should work in this case, if everything is fine right? No need for .war? I've checked every possible solution out there. Tch.

Comment: @monkeyintern What do you mean? Are you using an embedded server instead of deploying in a web server?

Comment: Yes, I tried to configure tomcat inside eclipse and deploy there. Would it be beneficial to change the approach? I don't know enough to see if that'd make a difference but I could try, no doubt

Comment: @monkeyintern Eclipse is handling the deployment for you. I thought you meant you were embedding the server into your application. You current approach is just fine. I think it's a configuration/dependencies problem. Try removing the `jersey-server` dependency and use only the `jersey-servlet` dependency. With it, you should have no `ClassNotFoundException`. Additionally, check [Jersey 1.x documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/index.html). The [chapter 11](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/chapter_deps.html) gives you a good overview about the dependencies.